# Ubuntu boot option does not appear while booting; installed Ubuntu with Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a separate disk , (that previously was unallocated space ) following the link:

[Link to the installation guide](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/22/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-11-04/)

Running the installer from `Try Ubuntu` option. Installation was carried out successfully. I can even see all disks in Windows 8 Disk Manager but cant boot into Ubuntu, because there is no boot option for that. The system automatically logs into Windows 8. Holding on left shift key after the system boots up also does not help. Could you please guide me how to install the grub so that I have both options when I start up my PC? ( I have been messing up with my pc and ultimately blew up all my drive data )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to reinstall grub loader in order to display both Ubuntu and Windows at startup.

You can do it with boot-repair software, it will install grub on your system, for that boot any Ubuntu on pendrive or removable media and start it as "try Ubuntu" then goto terminal and install boot-repair by following command.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (sudo boot-repair &)

boot-repair
```

Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

for more information visit [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Managed to repair it by running Boot repair. thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple answer would be to boot into the live CD/USB and run `Boot Repair`

Boot Repair PPA

- Boot into Live CD/USB.
- Type the following in terminal(one line at a time)

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
  sudo apt-get update  
  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
  ```
- Run `Boot Repair`

  > > Type in terminal
  > >     `sudo boot-repair`
  > >
  > > **or**
  > >
  > > type in Unity dash
  > >     `Boot Repair`
- Click the `Recommended repair` button
  [image]

After the process is finished close everything.
This should solve your problem.