# dual boot with windows 8

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8

I have installed ubuntu 12.10 64-bit alonside windows8 64 bit. After installation I am unable to boot windows 8. I have tried the dvd repair for windows and it says couldn't fix the issue. I have used UEFI installation for both ubuntu and windows 8. I am using a dell vostro 2520  model laptop. Help please

sudo add-apt : it says the command not found. :(

Answer (score 1):

A very simple answer would be to boot into the live CD/USB and run `Boot Repair`

Boot Repair PPA

- Boot into Live CD/USB.
- Type the following in terminal(one line at a time)

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
  sudo apt-get update  
  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
  ```
- Run `Boot Repair`

  > > Type in terminal
  > >     `sudo boot-repair`
  > >
  > > **or**
  > >
  > > type in Unity dash
  > >     `Boot Repair`
- Click the `Recommended repair` button
  [image]

After the process is finished close everything.
This should solve your problem.

---

I have already answered a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/278490/29470)

Comment: sudo add-apt : it says the command not found. I have booted the live usb into ubuntu in efi mode.

Comment: @user148043 im very sorry - made changes the the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

Comment: After this operation, 6,427 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  glade2script boot-sav boot-repair boot-sav-extra
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes i got this error while doing apt-get install -y boot-repair

Comment: Download it. No need to worry, its safe. :)

Comment: @user148043 if it has helped you dont forget to mark the answer as the correct one